# Web Service - issues in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, wpf, vb.net, web-services

Issue with our web service - when trying to get the information from the web service we're getting an error: "404 not found".

Can anyone see what could be the problem?

We're expecting back a JSON string.

**Service1.svc.vb**

```html
<ServiceContract(Namespace:="OurWebsiteURL-Here")>
<ServiceBehavior(Namespace:="OurWebsiteURL-Here")>
Public Class Service1

    <OperationContract()>
    <WebGet(UriTemplate:="/getPersonInfo/?personID={personID}&companyCode={companyCode}", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
    Public Function getPersonInfo(ByVal personID As String, ByVal companyCode As String) As String
               Dim dba As New DBAccess
        Dim person As New PersonInfo
        Dim m_SelPerson As String = String.Empty
        Dim ds As DataSet = dba.GetPersonInfo(personID, companyCode)
        If Not ds Is Nothing Then
      
            Dim dr As DataRow = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)
            person = New PersonInfo
      
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr("UserID")) Then
                person.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(dr("UserID"))
            End If
            person.PersonID = Convert.ToInt32(dr("PersonID"))
            person.Company = dr("Company")
            If Not IsDBNull(dr("Title")) Then
                person.Title = dr("Title")
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(dr("CellNum")) Then
                person.CellNum = dr("CellNum")
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(dr("EmergencyPhone")) Then
                person.EmergencyPhone = dr("EmergencyPhone")
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(dr("Email")) Then
                person.Email = dr("Email")
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(dr("PersonImageName")) Then
                person.PersonImageName = dr("PersonImageName")
            End If
            'person.PersonImageName = dr("PersonImageName")
            Dim oSerilzer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
            m_SelPerson = oSerilzer.Serialize(person)
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        End If
        'Return New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(m_SelPerson))
        Return m_SelPerson
    End Function
```

**PersonInfo.vb**

```html
<DataContract()>
Public Class PersonInfo

    Private m_userID As Integer
    Private m_personID As Integer
    Private m_title As String
    Private m_company As String
    Private m_cellNum As String
    Private m_emergencyPhone As String
    Private m_email As String
    Private m_PersonImageName As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property UserID() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_userID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_userID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property PersonID() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_personID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_personID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Title() As String
        Get
            Return m_title
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_title = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Company() As String
        Get
            Return m_company
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_company = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property CellNum() As String
        Get
            Return m_cellNum
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_cellNum = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property EmergencyPhone() As String
        Get
            Return m_emergencyPhone
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_emergencyPhone = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Email() As String
        Get
            Return m_email
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_email = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property PersonImageName As String
        Get
            Return m_PersonImageName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_PersonImageName = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

**Web.config**

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalDBConnectionTest" connectionString="data source=URL;initial catalog=TEST;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=test;Connection Timeout=60" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <customErrors mode="On"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="4800" maxRequestLength="500000000"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SoapEndpointBinding"
                 closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="250000000"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="250000000"
                 openTimeout="00:10:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="4500000" maxStringContentLength="4500000" maxBytesPerRead="40960000" maxNameTableCharCount="250000000" maxArrayLength="4500000"/>
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="RestEndpointBinding"
                 closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="250000000"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="250000000"
                 openTimeout="00:10:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="4500000" maxStringContentLength="4500000" maxBytesPerRead="40960000" maxNameTableCharCount="250000000" maxArrayLength="4500000"/>
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFDispatchWebService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="SOAP" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFDispatchWebService.Service1" bindingConfiguration="SoapEndpointBinding" bindingNamespace="OurURL-HERE" />
        <endpoint address="REST" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFDispatchWebService.Service1" bindingConfiguration="RestEndpointBinding" bindingNamespace="OurURL-HERE" behaviorConfiguration="RestEndpointBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RestEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <security >
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000"></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**DBAccess**

```html
 Public Function GetPersonInfo(ByVal personID As String, ByVal companyCode As String) As DataSet
        Dim ds As DataSet = Nothing

        Try
            ' Prepare the arguement list
            Dim storedProc As String = "spGetPersonInfoFromPersonID"
            Dim SqlParameterList As New List(Of SqlParameter)
            SqlParameterList.Add(New SqlParameter("@inPersonID", Convert.ToInt32(personID)))

            ' Execute the SP and store the dataset
            ds = SQLHelper.ExecuteNonQueryDataSet(Globals.GetConnectionStringMain(companyCode), CommandType.StoredProcedure, storedProc, SqlParameterList.ToArray())

            ' Check for an empty dataset
            If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count <= 0 Then
                ds = Nothing
            End If
        Catch
        End Try

        Return ds
    End Function
```

Error that we're getting after debugging and getting a Valid JSON File:

failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9376004. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

```html
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Service1.getPersonInfo(String personID, String companyCode)
   at Service1Client.getPersonInfo(String personID, String companyCode)

Inner Exception:
The HTTP request to 'http://localhost:56329/Service1.svc/SOAP' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:59.9680000. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)

Inner Exception:
The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

Comment: While not reading all of your code, I would say a good first step in testing a service whether it's your or a third party's is to just a free tool call 'Fiddler' made by Telerik.  You may have an issue with simply the call or the request format that has nothing to do with your .NET setup.  Simply using Fiddler I could open it up, go to 'Composer' and do something like: GET (from a dropdown) and 'https://service/moreinfo'(your service).  Then hit execute.  If you see a non 200 (success web request) on the side, you can hit inspectors and 'TextView' and see an error reason.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tested it with WebInvoke Method:="GET" and the data coming back as expected but when publishing it to the live server we're getting error 404 not found.

Comment: Is it being deployed to a server that has shared hosting? I notice you're using paths that are root-linked, e.g. UriTemplate:="/getPersonInfo/

Comment: Yes we're using shared hosting server.Anyone knows what can cause the issue after debugging the web service we're getting a prompt window with the attached error above.